# Jquery request doesn't reach servlet

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, servlets

I am tring a Ajax project.
I use servlet, jquery in html with Google app engine.

**web.xml XML mapping**

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>ContactsWithAjaxServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.ContactsWithAjaxServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ContactsWithAjaxServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ContactsWithAjaxServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

**Html**

```
<form name="addform">
      <table>
<tr><td>First Name:</td><td> <input type="text" name="name"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Last Name:</td><td> <input type="text" name="lname"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Add" name="Add" id="Add"/></td>
        <td><input type="reset" value="reset"/></td></tr>
       </table>
      </form>
```

**Servlet**

```
    package com;

    public class ContactsWithAjaxServlet extends HttpServlet {

            public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
                    throws IOException {
                resp.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
                resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); // E
PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
            out.println(""); //Html codes in several out.println 
out.flush();
}
```

**JQuery within html**

```
$(document).ready(function() {                                   
    $('#Add').click(function() {                        
      $.get('/ContactsWithAjaxServlet', function(responseText) {    
        $('p').text("<h1>Hello</h1>");                         
      });
    });
  });
```

Is there anything wrong in my code. The request from jquery doesn;t hit the servlet. I tried changing the url in jquery method. Please help me with the url mapping. I couldn;t find other materials to be useful.

Comment: what is the url that you have constructed to hit the server from jquery

Comment: Include your code for the AJAX request

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE

Looks like your url for servlet is correct. First make sure you can call it directly using browser and `http://localhost:8888/ContactsWithAjaxServlet`

Then make your form correctly invoke servelt without Ajax. Fix the form tag by adding action and method attributes, and comment javascript for a moment.

```
<form name="addform" method="GET" action="/ContactsWithAjaxServlet">
```

If that all works, you can think of using Ajax, if you really need it.
If you don't want whole page to reload you will either need to block form submition or change `Add` button type from `submit` to `button`.

```
<input type="button" value="Add" name="Add" id="Add"/>
```

add `id` to your form, to be able to query it easier

```
<form name="addform" id="addform">
```

and then read the form data and manually call the servlet:

```
$(document).ready(function() {                                   
    $('#Add').click(function() {                        
      $.get('/ContactsWithAjaxServlet', $("#addform").serialize(), function(responseText) {    
        $('p').text("<h1>Hello</h1>");                         
      });
    });
  });
```

Comment: What does context root mean? Is it the project's name? Since eclipse has configured every folder by default, I don;t remember the structure. Can you provide me with an example?

Comment: The URL of your application so to speak.

Comment: If you are deploying .war file it is usually name of the war file.  How are you deploying application? What application server are you using? @SibichakravarthyGunasekaran

Comment: I use google app engine to run my project. My project has war folder. My project name is ContactsWithAjax. I don;t know how to deal with the context. Please Help.

Comment: @SibichakravarthyGunasekaran  So try /ContactsWithAjax/ContactsWithAjaxServlet url. You can type it also in your browser to see if it returns any data.

Comment: No. It is not coming. Do the project name and servlet-name in xml file be same? I really don;t understand the url mapping in xml file as well as in html file. Can you suggest me anyother ways?

Comment: Can you see any page from your project (html, jsp, anything)? What is any working URL are you using to access any resource from your project?

Comment: @SibichakravarthyGunasekaran How are you accessing html in your project?

Comment: Since I have given index.html as welcome file, it gets loaded. But the request form this page via a jquery to ContactsWithAjaxServlet is not received.  By default, the project gets loaded at localhost:8888/ I couldn't see any name behind this path.  When I click add button, the link I could see is http://localhost:8888/?name=&lname=&number=&email=&Add=Add. I can;t access the project with any of the  possible urls. I tried with putting servlet name, mapping name after the localhost but i couldn;t access the project.

Comment: @SibichakravarthyGunasekaran Try to type in your browser (not in jquery request) http://localhost:8888/ContactsWithAjaxServlet and see if it correctly invokes the servlet

Comment: @SibichakravarthyGunasekaran Based on your info, this url should be correct. So maybe your application is not compiled/deployed correctly. Check if you have any information in logs when application is deployed and started.